# How comapre 2 json filtered with multiple json path with single comparisson?

Tags: java, json, jsonpath, jsonassert

There are 2 json, there multiple paths which is needed to be applied on both json. Then these jsons should be compared via some assert in test. The ide solution whould be:

```
Stirng actualJson - ....
Stirng expectedJson - ....
Stirng actualJsonFiltered - filter(actualJson, lisofJsonPath);
Stirng expectedJsonFiltered - filter(expectedJson, lisofJsonPath);

JSONAssert.assertEquals(actualJsonFiltered, expectedJsonFiltered);
```

What is **not** a solutiom:
1. Any code like that:

```
for(String p: lisofJsonPath) {
    assertEquals(JsonPath.read(actualJson, p), JsonPath.read(expectedJson , p);
}
```

It is needed to filter jsons and show/fail with all existing path. Show error that several paths are not matches. **Not** one by one json path matching.

2. `org.assertj.core.api.SoftAssertions` - also is not a solution because it is hard to understand from message what assetons are failed.
3. harcrest `allOf`/`anyOf` also is not a solution because it fails on first matched asseretion not combinig them.

**P.S.** Any suggestions for json diff visualizations are wellcome. The ideal way looks like [this](https://benjamine.github.io/jsondiffpatch/demo/index.html). (but this is in javascript)

Answer (score 0):

First,
accept the following:

1. JSON is an unordered collection of key-value pairs.
2. It is hard to compare an unordered collection of anything.
3. If you order the key-value pairs (sorted by key) and you represent the JSON value as a String (for example: "{\"keyA\":\"blam\",\"keyB\":\"kapow\"}") you can compare the JSON values using a string comparison.

I will call the sorted form of JSON "cannonical JSON form".

Once you accept the above as true and/or real,
this becomes the solution to your problem:

1. Create a tool (perhaps a single class) that accepts JSON and outputs the cannonical JSON form (this is the non-trivial portion of this solution):
2. Get the canonical JSON form for both of your JSON values.
3. Compare the cannonical JSON forms using `assertEquals`.